# What is the key advantage (regarding scalability) of the cookie + cache mechanism in Play 2.0 compared to Java EE HttpSession?

Tags: jakarta-ee, playframework-2.0

I understand that we don't like to maintain session state on server for scalability reasons in general, but I just don't see why the approach taken by Play 2.0 is said to be better than the old school HttpSession.

A major difference I see is the fact, that the HttpSession implementation is provided by the container, and hence scaling capabilities with HttpSession depends on it.

Comment: added playframework tag, as this question is applicable to play 1 or 2, as the session and caching philosophy are the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of advantages with this. In essence, the session model in Play promotes a share nothing architecture. This means that each action you execute, which if you follow the pattern as Play promotes, is a RESTful request, the execution of the action is entirely self contained. This means that each request can be unit tested individually, and your application built up as a set of discrete functions.

The principle here, is that the less coupling between each action, and the less conversational state that is being handled by a fat session, the cleaner and more robust your code becomes.

As a side effect, you also have the easy scaling through adding more nodes horizontally, which is usually cheaper than vertical scaling, and less complex and risky than sticky sessions.

Comment: What if there simply IS state in the application? Wouldn't the self contained request need to get it from somewhere, like e.g. a central database for each request?

Comment: yes, it would get it from a databsae, or initially from a cache, and if that doesn't exist, then the database. The idea is that the http server can die, and another server take over because state is not held at the app server layer...it therefore makes the architecture more robust (at the loss of performance due to DB reads)

Answer (score 4):

Using a container managed session (and its encapsulated state) means when you want to scale horizontally, the systems involved will also have to make sure they replicate this state because your application will not work without it. A client that uses your application is effectively bound to the *particular* node the user happens to be directed to.

In contrast; when your application maintains no real session state at any point (as your Play application should) it's very easy to scale horizontally: just add more nodes that run the application and make sure that the front-end HTTP server knows about the new nodes. No fancy algorithms and "enterprise platforms" to replicate and maintain sessions across all nodes.

Comment: IMHO, Replication is not bound to the JEE HttpSession per se. It is just a "feature" certain containers chose to implement. They could just as well choose to put the session in a global store.

Comment: @AndreasSteffan Even when sessions are stored in a global store, the global store is something you have to foresee and maintain. **If** you have this infrastructure and have the people to support it, that's great. Sessions aren't *bad*, it's just that the stateless approach is often much easier and more efficient (both towards scalability and development) - IMO :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is actually a little more complicated than that. Play actually pushes a **stateless** application architecture. Meaning, you are not storing any data in the session. Nothing, except the credentials may to be stored.

**First rule** : Session storage is deported to the database. Instead of fetching data from the session, get it from the database. Scalability is way easier for databases than JVM applications.

**Second rule** : Nothing is stored other then the credentials. Meaning, you will have to transmit information otherwise for conversationnel states. There are two mains ways of doing this. Using hidden fields, which in my opinion is not the best way. Secondly use absolute URLs. Create a **URL** containing ids, searches and other.

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't see anything prohibiting the container to back the HttpSession implementation with a database.

Comment: Nothing. You could do that. But then still, there is no strong typing in session. How about object lifecycles? From what moment is your object obsolete and when do you empty the session? Generally java dev's dont do that. They count on the garbage collector. And how about session timeouts? How do you handle those? The easiest way to handle all this is to avoid session and design stateless applications.

Comment: >Instead of fetching data from the session, get it from the database - But is your application *stateless* then, or are you replacing distributed session storage (the http session on each node) with one central session storage (the DB)?